# How do I specify an array argument for trimmean function, when I am selecting from cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using `TRIMMEAN` formula in Excel. My input data cannot be selected into an array. This is what I would like to do:
compute mean (with outlier removal) of six values in cells i2, i98, i194, i290,...

I have tried this

```
=trimmean({I2;I98;I194;I290;I386;I482}, 0.2)
```

How do I create an array of the six values? Is there a way to use trimmean in this case?

Comment: I gave my vote to Scott's answer, but if I were asked to solve this issue I would probably add a helper column to label the row number of each value in Column I, and then create a small look up table to look for the values in Column I at specific location (by using VLOOKUP or INDEX+MATCH), so all values you are looking for will be positioned in an array, and then you can use the TRIMMEAN function by referencing the array.

Comment: Try:  `=trimmean((I2;I98;I194;I290;I386;I482), 0.2)`.  An equivalent formula seems to work here.  Note that the non-contiguous range is enclosed in parentheses, not braces.

Answer (score 3):

to do that you will need INDEX and Some Math:

```
=TRIMMEAN(INDEX(I:I,N(IF({1},(ROW(1:6)-1)*96+2))),0.2)
```

This is an array formula that needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

The INDEX passes an array of those values starting with row 2 and then for the next 5 rows adding 96.

Comment: I thought this might be the approach, +1.

Answer (score 2):

`TRIMMEAN` seems to accept a non-contiguous range if you enclose the non-contiguous range within parentheses `()`

[image]